# NSSortDescriptor in Swift - sort by days left to next birthday

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on my first swift app. It's a simple Birthday list which stores Birthdays to CoreData with name, date of birth (as NSDate) and shows them in a table-view.

Now what I try doing is sorting that table-view by days-left to the next Birthday.

I already show "days-left" in the table view cell by calculating the next Birthday and the "days-left" every time I load the table-view - like this:

```
    let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: NSDate(), toDate: nextBirthDay, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
```

How can I now sort the table-view by diffDateComponents?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an other key/row to your core-data model witch describes the difference between the day of birth and the actual day. It can be updated when the model is loaded.

Use this key/row as sort-descriptor.

Comment: thank you. This was my initial though. But could not make that work - see my "answer" above - couldn't get that into the comment

Answer (score 0):

I consider your table data array that means array of `NSDate` objects as `var birthdays = [NSDate]()`.
Then I declare a `NSDateComponents` Array as like `var daysLeftArray = [NSDateComponents]()`. Then append the every time difference into the array.

```
for date in birthdays{
    let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate: NSDate(), toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
    daysLeftArray.append(diffDateComponents)
}
```

Now sort the array like this:

```
daysLeftArray.sortInPlace({(first, second) in
    first.day < second.day  // assending order. Put '>' for decending order
})
```